# how do I use jQuery to fire one common handler for more than one different events triggers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my web page I have two hyper links which do almost similar thing when an onclick event happens. Just to finish up I copy pasted the code twice and changed the event targets, so I essentially have code similar to this

```
$('#editprofilebutton').click(function(){/*do some magical stuff here*/});
$('#changepassbutton').click(function(){/*do some magical stuff here*/});
```

How can I  remove this duplication and have some thing like `$('#editprofilebutton' or '#changepassbutton').click(function(){/*do some magical stuff here*/});`?

Comment: :D I used it now, I was doing `$('#editprofilebutton', '#changepassbutton').click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#editprofilebutton, #changepassbutton').click(function(){/*do some magical stuff here*/});
```

Docs: [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
$('#editprofilebutton, #changepassbutton').click(function() {
    // do magical stuff
});
```

Or:

```
var doMagicalStuff = function() {
    // do magical stuff
};

// now you can assign doMagicalStuff to as many elements as you want in as
// many different places as you want:

$('#editprofilebutton,#changepassbutton').click(doMagicalStuff);

// and you can assign it later on to another button if necessary. maybe you
// dynamically add a button that also needs to do magic. who doesn't want to
// do magic?

$('#someotherbutton').click(doMagicalStuff);
```